# YUM error. Is this a cert error

Tags: linux, centos, python, yum, update

```
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/bin/yum'
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: New client connected
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrt-server[3508]: Saved Python crash dump of pid 3151 to /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2012-11-13-13:38:57-3151
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Directory 'pyhook-2012-11-13-13:38:57-3151' creation detected
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-former
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-release
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-rhx
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Package 'yum' isn't signed with proper key
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2012-11-13-13:38:57-3151' exited with 1
Nov 13 13:38:57 host abrtd: Corrupted or bad directory /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2012-11-13-13:38:57-3151, deleting
```

There is also nothing in the crash dump file. Ideas?

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
An error has occurred:
Internal Server Error
See /var/log/up2date for more information
```

Is yum broken

Comment: It would be helpful to know what distro and version you are running. Do the GPG keys listed in the error messages exist on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Is this (or was it) RHEL or CentOS (which you used for tag)? I hope...

#### RHEL:

What does `rpm -qa | grep redhat-release` show? `rpm -V redhat-release-server-6Server` (use the packge from 1st step)? If it's not installed or is corrupted, you may want to obtain the package from a secure source and reinstall it.

In case it is

#### CentOS:

I do not think CentOS uses *redhat* keys or RHN - were you trying to migrate from RHEL to CentOS or vice-versa? Or you just followed CentOS' deployment guide?\

In that case, you should disable the RHN and install centos repos instead - follow CentOS' migration guide.

You should be able to get corresponding `centos-release-...` package from `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/YOUR_VERSION/os/x86_64/Packages/`.